# Aligning without a table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

So, I understand that tables are the spawn of satan. How should I align this without a table?

I have a bunch of input fields, each with a label to the left of it, and I would like the left side of the input fields to be aligned. Bad ascii art follows:

```
                                   name ________________    
                          date of birth ________________  
 Shakespeare villain I would like to be ________________  
                  favo(u)rite do(gh)nut ________________  
                      pet's blood group ________________  
                   mother's maiden name ________________  
         favo(u)rite Led Zeppelin track ________________
```

I don't need exact code, just to be told how to do it.

[This page](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) looks incredibly helpful, but how do I do it with the text & input fileds?

Maybe a <div> with the text floating right and the input field vertically aligned at 50%  ?

Comment: <div> provide better layout options as compared to tables

Comment: Check out my answer below. Divided into 2x50%, with line-height set, and vertical align middle. Also for bonus points I included ellipsis backfall if your labels grow out of proportions. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try `display: table-cell;`

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide DOM structure for your styles?

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wrapper div.td1 {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* added incase of too long label text */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="td1">name</div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">date of birth</div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">Shakespeare villain I would like to be</div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">favo(u)rite do(gh)nut</div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">pet's blood grou </div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">mother's maiden name</div><div><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="td1">favo(u)rite Led Zeppelin track</div><div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where that width:50% comes from?

Comment: #wrapper div gives all divs inside #wrapper 50% width. :)

Comment: What on that ASCII art tells you that first column shall be 50% of container?

Comment: How "vertically aligned at 50%" is related to `width:50%` ?

Comment: Well then my curious friend, it must have been by sheer eye measurement

Answer (score -2):

The best thing you can get here is to recreate table layout with different DOM elements plus some display:table-*** declarations :

```css
div.parent { display:table; }
div.parent > row { display:table-row; }
div.parent > row > * { display:table-cell; }
div.parent > row > label { text-align:right; padding: 0 0.25em; }
div.parent > row > label::after { content:":"; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <row>
    <label>name</label>
       <p>_____________</p>
  </row><row>  
    <label>date of birth</label>
       <p>_____________</p>    
  </row><row>      
    <label>Shakespeare villain I would like to be</label>
       <p>_____________</p>    
  </row><row>  
    <label>favo(u)rite do(gh)nut</label>
       <p>_____________</p>    
  </row><row>      
    <label>pet's blood group</label>
       <p>_____________</p>    
  </row><row>      
    <label>mother's maiden name</label>
       <p>_____________</p>    
  </row><row>      
    <label>favo(u)rite Led Zeppelin track</label>
       <p>_____________</p>
  </row>      
</div>
```

Comment: What about small screens and not still being aligned?

Comment: On small screens you will use @media query and different layout:

`@media small-screen { div.parent > row > * { display:block; }}`

In the same way as it is done in bootstrap and the like column systems.

Answer (score -2):

## A touch of flex

> This may have some limitations depending on the rest of your layout; **treat it as an experiment**.

To reduce the amount of HTML used along with a tiny amount of CSS, we can play around with a flexbox layout.

**Compatibility:** [IE 11+ and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

The `<form>` container is given `display: flex` and, to align each label in the center of its input, `align-items: center`. `flex-wrap: wrap` is used to form rows.

The inputs and labels are given `flex: 1 1 50%`. This gives them an initial width of 50% which will then grow and shrink with the container. The initial value of 50% can be changed to make the inputs wider or smaller, as long as the label and inputs initial values add up to 100%.

The rows are spaced out with `margin: 5px 0 5px` on the inputs to provide a top and bottom margin. The top and bottom margin value should remain the same so the labels are centered.

`box-sizing: border-box` incorporates border and padding into the elements width and height

[A guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is very useful.

#### Full Example

The form can be nicely controlled with `min-width` and `max-width` to maintain some flexibility.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
input {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="label1">This is a really long label</label>
  <input id="label1" type="text">
  <label for="label2">Smaller label</label>
  <input id="label2" type="text">
  <label for="label3">Tiny</label>
  <input id="label3" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: The ASCII art implies that first column has width of widest label (first column) but not 50% or anything fixed like that.

Comment: It can be adjusted only if you can guarantee that font you use exists on target machine. In 99% cases you simply cannot guarantee that. And yet  such an adjustment is sensitive to content of labels. Ideally good CSS design shall be textual content agnostic. Think of i18n and the like.

Comment: In your sample, it is enough space to render label without wrapping. But in your case it wraps due to fixed width. Not that good UX quality. Flex boxes cannot do table alike layouts in general. They are about free space distribution but far from tabular alignment.

Comment: @c-smile - True, this isn't a true "table substitute". My main idea is to render the form without the need for extra HTML; it just needs the form and the inputs/labels with a tiny amount of CSS.

Comment: Conceptually CSS Grid ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/ )  may help in this case. But we are not there yet. In Sciter ( http://sciter.com/docs/flex-flow/flex-layout.htm ) I've introduced `flow:row(label,input)` layout for that purpose but that's Sciter specific.